# What are the main issues with a db4o server without the persistent classes available?

Tags: configuration, db4o

I was told in a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187130/db4o-client-server-mode-without-persistent-class-unique-constraint-indexes) that there can be issues when using db4o server without persistent classes. On the Versant web site, they just say that native queries won't be available.

So what are the issues possible in this particular configuration, except less features ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some features do not work:

- All query methods except SODA queries do not work.
- Some type of objects my create issues like enums etc.

The main concern is just the 'stability' and 'matureness' of this feature. db4o hasn't been design to work without the classes available. The test-suite and feature design is centered around scenarios with classes available.

Or from the internal implementation standpoint: The 'generic'-reflection layer is very brittle. That's the component which is required for this feature.

Well if up for taking a risk and only use SODA as query engine you can try it. However if you rather do not run into bugs / limitations than avoid it.

Comment: Hi Gamlor, sure I will avoid it, my production application is critical so I won't do it. Thank you for your detailled point. I was looking for arguments against. And you gice them to me. I think versant, should offically saying it is unsupported . Thanks again.

Comment: I think it's not really promoted as a feature or is it? It's maybe not clearly enough stated that the 'with classes' server is expected use case. Added a issue for that: http://tracker.db4o.com/browse/DOC-694